# How to connect hiveserver2 from java code using JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc, hive

Adding my code bellow. When i am trying to run the code it is showing "Connection timed out" error. I am trying this code from a separate system. Basically i am trying to remotely connect to hiveserver2 from my local laptop.

```
package hive_test;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
public class HiveJdbcClientv1 {
  private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
  /**
   * @param args
   * @throws SQLException
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
      try {
      Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
    //replace "hive" here with the name of the user the queries should run as
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:10000/default", "hive", "");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String tableName = "testHiveDriverTable";
    stmt.execute("drop table if exists " + tableName);
    stmt.execute("create table " + tableName + " (key int, value string)");
    // show tables
    // String sql = "show tables '" + tableName + "'";
    String sql = ("show tables");
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    if (res.next()) {
        System.out.println(res.getString(1));
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: `telnet xxx.xxx.xx.xxx 10000`... Is this port responding? Your error is not Java related